# Imágenes para Anuncios Reducidos

Tags: bug, traducciones

En el artículo de ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads se incluye una imagen en inglés y con diseño obsoleto. A continuación la imagen en español.

[image]

Referencia

[¿Cómo subimos imágenes?](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

El [PR](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/pull/14) para actualizar la imagen ya fue revisado y aprobado.